# Como criar múltiplas páginas iniciais em um único portal no Plone?

Tags: python, cms

Num portal Plone, como em qualquer CMS, o conteúdo é inserido como imagens, arquivos, pastas, páginas, notícias etc. Tudo isso é acessado através de uma Página Inicial "HOME" com menus e conteúdo que direciona o usuário pelo portal...

É possível criar mais de uma página "HOME" customizável num único portal? Como se faz? É pela administração do Plone ou via Python e arquivos de configuração?

É para um órgão que tem seu portal, mas o setor de RH quer uma página no estilo "home" para o seu conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esta é uma página estilo "HOME"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esta é uma página estilo "Lista de Conteúdo" que são os sub-itens do Menu "Pessoal"

Comment: Qual versão do plone está usando?

Comment: 3.5 estou usando há apenas uma semana no meu novo trabalho e tenho pouca experiência com esse cms. Estou mais familiarizado com Joomla e Drupal.

Comment: Se eu bem entendi a sua pergunta, você deseja criar uma página inicial para cada seção do seu portal, isto é, Se eu clicar na raiz do portal ele carrega uma "página inicial" se eu clicar em RH, ele carrega uma "página inicial" do setor dele. Neste caso, na versão 3.5 do Plone, tem um produto chamado [CMFContentPanels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CMFContentPanels), você instala esse produto e em cada seção Cria seu panel, e adiciona ele como visão da pasta. Clicando em: Exibição > Selecionar um item como visão padrão. E depois você seleciona o item criado anteriormente.